# Can (incomplete) database compacting cause incorrect query results?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

So my team uses an Access 2007 database every day. This database has several tables, which are linked via ODBC to an enterprise size T-SQL database.

This database is about 5-6 years old now, so I decided to set it to compact and repair on close.

Each day, my team has to open the database and refresh one particular query, which normally returns roughly around 280,000 records, give or take 20,000.

Well, this past week, something was causing this query to return significantly less records, usually exactly 59,000. Running the same query of the same enterprise database in SQL Server reveals that the actual amount of rows returned by this query should be roughly 280,000, as usual.

I have come to learn that my team was closing the Access Database by pressing `esc` during exit (to stop compacting while it was in process) because they are typically in a hurry.

Is it possible that stopping the database from compacting in this manner could directly affect the results of this query?

Comment: Just guessing here, have you tried refreshing the links on the 'broken' database and then checked your query?

Comment: Anecdotal: I interrupt the compacting by pressing `esc` most of the time and personally have never noticed issues as a result of that.  Perhaps try decompiling and compact/repair the database.

Comment: Actually, when I removed the Compact on Close setting, the query worked properly, and returned the correct # of rows. This seems strange, as I didn't think that interrupting the compacting/repairing of a DB could cause an issue so blatant as this. Which is what lead me to ask the question in the first place lol.